# What is the chromatic number of the "conic hypergraph" on a non-singular plane cubic?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, graph-theory, elliptic-curves, graph-colorings

Can we color the points of a complex non-singular plane cubic curve with finitely many colors so that no conic intersects the curve at 6 distinct points of the same color?

If so, what is the smallest number of such colors?

Comment: There's a difference between an *elliptic curve* and a *non-singular cubic plane curve* (with marked point). The latter is an example of the former, but elliptic curves can be embedded in higher dimensional projective spaces, where it doesn't makes sense to intersect them with a conic. For that matter, $\mathbb C/L$ is a complex elliptic curve, where $L$ is a lattice. Sorry to nit-pick. When formulated in terms of intersections of (smooth) plane curves, it sounds like an interesting problem.

Comment: @JoeSilverman, Thank you, I edited to fix that.

Comment: +1 for the title. Completely incomprehensible to anyone but those in the know!

Answer (score 9):

You mean the six points to be distinct, of course (or not all six points to be the same point).

Fixing the analytic identification $(\wp(z),\wp'(z))$ with $T = \mathbb{C}/\mathbb{\Lambda}$, the Abel-Jacobi theorem implies that the six points of intersection of $E \subset \mathbb{CP}^2$ with any conic sum to zero on the torus. Now take the fundamental parallelogram $P$ of $\Lambda$, subdivide it into $36$ equal subparallelograms, and use $72$ colors so that monochromatic subsets of $P$ are either interior points of one of the subparallelograms or of its left or down boundary edges, or else a single lattice point from the subdivision of $P$ (a $6$-division point).

Comment: Very nice idea!

Comment: For the vertices, you can just color them $5$ at a time, so this reduces the number of colors to $44$, but I suspect it should be lower than that.

Comment: It could be interesting to consider a higher dimensional version of this. Take $X$ a projective variety, fix an integer $r \geq 2$ and a base point $Q$, and ask that there be no monochromatic $(P_1, \ldots, P_r)$ of distinct points so that the zero-cycle $\sum_1^r [P_i] - r[Q]$ be rationally equivalent to $0$. In general we cannot use the Albanese torus, and indeed, for projective space the answer is obviously negative. We could ask for examples other than subvarieties of abelian varieties where such a coloring is possible.

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov Very ambitious to look for higher-dimensional versions. But at least for intersections of curves of degree $d_1$ and $d_2$, I think that your nice construction will work by embedding the first curve in the Jacobian and dividing $\mathbb C^g/L$ up into enough little parallelograms so that no $d_1d_2$ points add to $0$. So that will give an upper bound for the "$(d_1,d_2)$-*chromatic number*." But finding the exact value seems challenging.